# Trouble reading data in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Trying to read a pushToken from a given user in the users collection (after an update operation on another collection) returns undefined

```js
exports.addDenuncia = functions.firestore
  .document('Denuncias/{denunciaID}')
  .onWrite((snap, context) => {
    const doc = snap.after.data()
    const classificadoId = doc.cid
    const idTo = doc.peerId

    db.collection('Classificados').doc(classificadoId)
      .update({
        aprovado: false
      })
      .then(r => {
        getToken(idTo).then(token => {
          // sendMsg...
        })
      }).catch(updateErr => {
        console.log("updateErr: " + updateErr)
      })

    async function getToken(id) {
      let response = "getTokenResponse"
      console.log("id in getToken: " + id)
      return db.collection('users').doc(id).get()
        .then(user => {
          console.log("user in getToken: " + user.data())
          response = user.data().pushToken
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log("error get userToken: " + e)
          response = e
        });
      return response
    }

    return null
  });
```

And this is from the FB console log:

-1:43:33.906 AM Function execution started

-1:43:36.799 AM Function execution took 2894 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

-1:43:43.797 AM id in getToken: Fm1RwJaVfmZoSgNEFHq4sbBgoEh1

-1:43:49.196 AM user in getToken: undefined

-1:43:49.196 AM error get userToken: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushToken' of undefined

-1:43:49.196 AM returned token: undefined

And we can see in this screenshot from the db that the doc does exist:

[image]

Hope someone can point me to what I'm doing wrong here.

added screenshot of second example of @Renaud as deployed:
[image: deployed function]

Comment: The first problem here is that you're not dealing with promises correctly at all. You're not returning a promise from the top level function that resolves when all the async work is complete, and your getToken function is *always* going to return "getTokenResponse".  Cloud Functions is not a very nice place to learn about how promises work.  I suggest taking some time to learn about JavaScript promises in an easier environment to learn how they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Doug wrote in his comment, you need to "return a promise from the top level function that resolves when all the async work is complete". He also explains that very well in the official video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/ (in particular the 3 videos titled "Learn JavaScript Promises"). You should definitely watch them, highly recommended!

So, the following modifications to your code should work (untested):

```
exports.addDenuncia = functions.firestore
    .document('Denuncias/{denunciaID}')
    .onWrite(async (snap, context) => {   // <- note the async keyword

        try {

            const doc = snap.after.data()
            const classificadoId = doc.cid
            const idTo = doc.peerId

            await db.collection('Classificados').doc(classificadoId)
                .update({
                    aprovado: false
                });

            const userToSnapshot = await db.collection('users').doc(idTo).get();
            const token = userToSnapshot.data().pushToken;

            await sendMsg(token);  // <- Here you should take extra care to correctly deal with the asynchronous character of the sendMsg operation

            return null;  // <-- This return is key, in order to indicate to the Cloud Function platform that all the asynchronous work is done

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }

    });
```

Since you use an `async` function in your code, I've used the `async/await` syntax but we could very well write it by chaining the promises with the `then()` method, as shown below.

Also, I am not sure, in your case, that it adds any value to put the code that gets the token in a function (unless you want to call it from other Cloud Functions but then you should move it out of the `addDenuncia` Cloud Function). That's why it has been replaced by two lines of code within the main `try` block.

### Version with chaining promises via the `then()` method

In this version we chain the different promises returned by the asynchronous methods with the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method. Compared to the `async/await` version above, it shows very clearly what means *"to return a promise from the top level function that resolves when all the asynchronous work is complete"*.

```
exports.addDenuncia = functions.firestore
    .document('Denuncias/{denunciaID}')
    .onWrite((snap, context) => {   // <- no more async keyword

        const doc = snap.after.data()
        const classificadoId = doc.cid
        const idTo = doc.peerId

        return db.collection('Classificados').doc(classificadoId)  // <- we return a promise from the top level function
            .update({
                aprovado: false
            })
            .then(() => {
                return db.collection('users').doc(idTo).get();
            })
            .then(userToSnapshot => {
                if {!userToSnapshot.exists) {
                   throw new Error('No document for the idTo user');
                }
                const token = userToSnapshot.data().pushToken;

                return sendMsg(token);   // Again, here we make the assumption that sendMsg is an asynchronous function
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                return null;
            })

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your first example gives:

-Function execution started

-TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushToken' of undefined
    at exports.addDenuncia.functions.firestore.document.onWrite (/srv/index.js:277:48)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

-Function execution took 3006 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

Comment: Are you sure there is a document corresponding to the user? Can you add `console.log(userToSnapshot.exists);`just before `const token = ...`.

Comment: added the line and now returns: User document data: undefined

Comment: Just for clarity, index.js starts with const functions = require('firebase-functions');
   const admin = require('firebase-admin');
   admin.initializeApp();  
   const db = admin.firestore();

Comment: The second example also returns undefined

Comment: That's strange... If you do in the second example `.then(userToSnapshot => {console.log(userToSnapshot.exists);
                const token = userToSnapshot.data().pushToken;` it should print `true` or `false` in the Firebase Cloud Function log. Are you sure there is no typo in your code?

Comment: Returns false. Added a screenshot above of the function as deployed.

Comment: Ok, so if `userToSnapshot.exists` returns `false` it means that the document with ID `idTo` in the `users` collection does **NOT** exist. I've adapted the code of the second example to deal with this problem -> the Cloud Function will log the error and terminate.

Comment: But as you can see in the db screenshot, the doc does exist and idTo in the log does return the correct doc id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206234/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-jaime).

Comment: Ok, my bad, a leading space creeped in peerId when getting saved to Denuncias. Sorry ;-) will continue with the rest now.

Comment: Ok, works as expected now. I ended up using your first example as it's so much more readable. Will be doing all my future Cloud Functions in this manner.